# MySQL validate_password Plugin active but not installed?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a problem with my mysql installation. I want to install phpmyadmin, but the installation cancels because of a too weak password. So i tried to set the global variables with `Mysql SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy = 0;`..
When i tried again, the same error comes up. Next, I've removed the `validate_password`-Plugin from mysql... Not fount?! I can install it, then this happens:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON     |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password.length             | 8      |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password.policy             | LOW    |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1      |
| validate_password_check_user_name    | ON     |
| validate_password_dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password_length             | 8      |
| validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password_number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password_policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password_special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

When i restart the Mysql Service, all settings i made on this `validate_passwort` Vars, reset to their default.

Installed Plugins:

```
mysql> SHOW PLUGINS
    -> ;
+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+---------+
| Name                            | Status   | Type               | Library        | License |
+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+---------+
| binlog                          | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| mysql_native_password           | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL           | GPL     |
| sha256_password                 | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL           | GPL     |
| caching_sha2_password           | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL           | GPL     |
| sha2_cache_cleaner              | ACTIVE   | AUDIT              | NULL           | GPL     |
| CSV                             | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| MEMORY                          | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| InnoDB                          | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_TRX                      | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP                      | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP_RESET                | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMPMEM                   | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET             | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX            | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET      | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE              | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU          | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS        | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO          | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_METRICS                  | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD      | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_DELETED               | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED         | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_CONFIG                | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE           | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE           | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_TABLES                   | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_TABLESTATS               | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_INDEXES                  | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_TABLESPACES              | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_COLUMNS                  | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_VIRTUAL                  | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_CACHED_INDEXES           | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| INNODB_SESSION_TEMP_TABLESPACES | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL           | GPL     |
| MyISAM                          | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| MRG_MYISAM                      | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA              | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| TempTable                       | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| ARCHIVE                         | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| BLACKHOLE                       | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| FEDERATED                       | DISABLED | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL           | GPL     |
| ngram                           | ACTIVE   | FTPARSER           | NULL           | GPL     |
| mysqlx_cache_cleaner            | ACTIVE   | AUDIT              | NULL           | GPL     |
| mysqlx                          | ACTIVE   | DAEMON             | NULL           | GPL     |
| auth_socket                     | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | auth_socket.so | GPL     |
+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+---------+
45 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin doesn't directly complain about the complexity of your MySQL password. How are you installing it (downloading directly from phpmyadmin.net, using a package manager, etc) and what is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: I install it via package manager (apt-get install phpmyadmin) The installation works but when the configration comes up, i enter the passwords and then its cancelled and mysql says my password „does not satisfy the current policy requirements“..

Comment: It's only for my local machine, so I don‘t need strong passwords :D